# NiFi DecryptContent - the cipher stream is too small to contain the salt

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm testing with NiFi and I've run into an error that I can't find explained anywhere.

I am using the EncryptContent processor with `MD5_AES128`, `NiFi Legacy KDF`, and a password.  I'm encrypting something about 500KB, and it encrypts fine.

If I immediately pipe the output of that operation into a second EncryptContent processor (set, obviously, to *decrypt* with the same settings), I get the error shown below:

`The cipher stream is too small to contain the salt`

Can anyone tell me what this means and what I need to do to fix it?

[image: DecryptContent error]

Comment: Can you use the provenance feature to examine the content claim of the flowfile between the `EncryptContent` and (decrypting) `EncryptContent` processors? The content length certainly appears long enough to contain the salt, but the processor is unable to parse it correctly. Can you please also specify what version of NiFi you are using?

Comment: I'll examine the content claim in the next hour or so -- running 1.4.0

Comment: Ok. In the meantime, here is an article breaking down the process that might shed some light on what's happening. Happy to take a look when you have more info. [How to Decrypt OpenSSL-encrypted Data in Apache NiFi](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/kbentry/5319/how-to-decrypt-openssl-encrypted-data-in-apache-ni.html)

Comment: Okay -- in a position to investigate.  How can I help?  Here's a pic of the data provenance event "CONTENT MODIFIED" related to the first (encrypt) action.  https://ibb.co/mMP0z6

Comment: Probably not much use, but here's my layout: https://ibb.co/m3U3mm

Comment: For what it's worth, I changed my Java security settings to allow Unlimited Strength and used the KDF `OpenSSL EVP_BytesToKey` instead and it works ...